Showing Info Text in Status bar as how "Merge By Distance" does
When "Merge By Distance" in action, I see in statusbar, some information like
"(infoicon)78 vertices removed" for a while (1-2 secs appears)
how can we do it in python blender API?

Use the report method of the Operator. Documentation
